# Help to get back old reputation and badges

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, badges

I had a profile whose link is https://math.stackexchange.com/users/294365/learnmore.

The problem is when I am logging in it using my e-mail subarshabnrj@gmail.com and password,I find my reputation is not showing and it has been reduced to 1 reputation and 1 badge.

I don't know why. Please help me to get back my old reputation.

**UPDATE**

Please don't close the question.I worked so hard to earn the reputation and badges.

Comment: If you're having trouble logging in, use the contact us link at the bottom of the page and describe your problem. The staff should be able to sort things out.

Comment: @PolyGeo why you people are closing the question,my problem is different.

Comment: I don't want to merge user accounts.I only want to login successfully to my account

Comment: @user551899 closing this question has no bearing on what happens to your account. You've already had an answer from a member of staff telling you what to do (and you said you'd already done so), so there's not much more this question can do.

Answer (score 4):

Drop us a support request via the [contact us](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) page, describe what happened (and anything you can think of that may be relevant - how long ago you were last able to log in successfully, if anything relevant happened that you can think of since then, etc.) and our support team will get back to you with some options and/or additional questions.

Comment: I dropped a support request but no one responded.Will you kindly do something?

Comment: I earned the reputations by doing so much hard work,they all got lost.Please help

Comment: Relax, sometimes it takes time for SE to get around to addressing support requests.